# Declaring an empty list

Tags: python

I just noticed that declaring two empty lists as:

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

produced an entirely different result as compared to:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
```

I don't this problem is related to the whole program as such, or that the result is important. Nevertheless here is [the whole program](http://pastebin.com/bYJ82T96). So is there any difference between the two ways of declaration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

Assignes the same empty list instance (`[]`) to both list1 and list2. This is because object instances are assigned by reference.

You can do this instead:

```
list1, list2 = [], []
```

to assign two different lists two the two variables.

You can check it as follows:

```
list1 = list2 = []
print id(list1)  # Same as id(list2)
print id(list2)  # Same as id(list1)

list1, list2 = [], []
print id(list1)  # Different than id(list2)
print id(list2)  # Different than id(list1)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

can be written as:

```
list2 = []
list1 = list2
```

All you're doing is making an alias (effectively).

Comment: But I thought a = b = 1 declared two different variable (not alias) each with value 1?

Comment: If you really want the nitty-gritty details, here's what happens. An integer object is constructed with a value of one. A reference to that object is assigned to `b`. And then that same reference is assigned to `a`. They both point at the exact same thing.

Comment: In python, ALL variables are just references. And actually my statement about "aliases" is slightly incorrect. Because if you assign `2` to `b`, `a` stays pointing at `1`. If you could somehow modify the `1` object though (you can't) they'd both be affected.

Comment: well, actually that's backwards, `list1` gets assigned *first*.  consider: `foo = ['b'] ; foo[:] = foo[0] = ['a'] ; foo` and `foo = ['b'] ; foo[0] = foo[:] = ['a'] ; foo`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: how can that be? I thought that python evaluated the right-hand side of an expression first.

Comment: @Chris: it does evaluate the right side expression, but then it does the assignments left to right.

Comment: Hmm... my naive notions about recursive descent parsing have just been shot in the face. I need to go lick my wounds.

Answer (score 4):

When you say:

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

there is only one empty list, and you point both names list1 and list2 to it.

When you say:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
```

there are two empty lists, each name gets a different one.

Keep in mind: assignment in Python never copies data.  So two names can point to the same mutable value (list), and they will both see whatever changes are made to it.